# Looping through array of objects by object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects with some information about a pop I am trying to fire. it looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "url":"www.fakeurl/redirect1",
      "providerName":"ebay",
      "retailerName":"eBay",
      "providerAndRetailer":"ebayeBay",
      "popAllowed":true
   },

   {  
      "url":"www.fakeurl/redirect2",
      "providerName":"pricerunner",
      "retailerName":"Currys",
      "providerAndRetailer":"pricerunnerCurrys",
      "popAllowed":true
   },
   {  
      "url":"www.fakeurl/redirect3",
      "providerName":"kelkoo",
      "retailerName":"Currys",
      "providerAndRetailer":"kelkooCurrys",
      "popAllowed":true
   },
   {  
      "url":"www.fakeurl/redirect4",
      "providerName":"ebay",
      "retailerName":"eBay",
      "providerAndRetailer":"ebayeBay",
      "popAllowed":true
   },
   {  
      "url":"www.fakeurl/redirect5",
      "providerName":"pricerunner",
      "retailerName":"Argos",
      "providerAndRetailer":"pricerunnerArgos",
      "popAllowed":true
   },
   {  
      "url":"www.fakeurl/redirect6",
      "providerName":"ebay",
      "retailerName":"eBay",
      "providerAndRetailer":"ebayeBay",
      "popAllowed":true
   },
   {  
      "url":"www.fakeurl/redirect7",
      "providerName":"ecn",
      "retailerName":"Argos",
      "providerAndRetailer":"ecnArgos",
      "popAllowed":true
   }
]
```

I also have a array of providers in which I would like the order to fire:

```
let acceptedProviders = ['ebay', 'connexity', 'ecn', 'kelkoo', 'nexttag', 'pricerunner', 'shopping'];
```

I would like to loop over my array in the order of my acceptedProviders. When a match is found with the "providerName" property in my object I want the loop to stop and add a property of "popAllowed": false, so then I can filter it out of the list. It would then loop again, still looking for the first name in my accepted providers array, if it doesnt find it, it moves onto the next until the list is exhausted. I have tried a for loop but I cant seem to get the results Im looking for. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How does the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the data and within each iteration set popAllowed by looking for that provider in accepted providers array

```js
let acceptedProviders = ['ebay', 'connexity', 'ecn', 'kelkoo', 'nexttag', 'pricerunner', 'shopping'];
let data = get_data();

data.forEach((item)=>{
  item.popAllowed = acceptedProviders.indexOf(item.providerName) === -1;
});

console.log(data);

function get_data() {
  return [{
      "url": "www.fakeurl/redirect1",
      "providerName": "ebay",
      "retailerName": "eBay",
      "providerAndRetailer": "ebayeBay",
      "popAllowed": true
    },

    {
      "url": "www.fakeurl/redirect2",
      "providerName": "pricerunner",
      "retailerName": "Currys",
      "providerAndRetailer": "pricerunnerCurrys",
      "popAllowed": true
    },
    {
      "url": "www.fakeurl/redirect3",
      "providerName": "kelkoo",
      "retailerName": "Currys",
      "providerAndRetailer": "kelkooCurrys",
      "popAllowed": true
    },
    {
      "url": "www.fakeurl/redirect4",
      "providerName": "ebay",
      "retailerName": "eBay",
      "providerAndRetailer": "ebayeBay",
      "popAllowed": true
    },
    {
      "url": "www.fakeurl/redirect5",
      "providerName": "pricerunner",
      "retailerName": "Argos",
      "providerAndRetailer": "pricerunnerArgos",
      "popAllowed": true
    },
    {
      "url": "www.fakeurl/redirect6",
      "providerName": "ebay",
      "retailerName": "eBay",
      "providerAndRetailer": "ebayeBay",
      "popAllowed": true
    },
    {
      "url": "www.fakeurl/redirect7",
      "providerName": "ecn",
      "retailerName": "Argos",
      "providerAndRetailer": "ecnArgos",
      "popAllowed": true
    }
  ];
}



//console.log(data)
```

Comment: im trying to avoid reordering the array of objects, because this is part of a bigger thing where a "order property" is set in a config and I pick it up in the JS and execute the link pops as specified by the config. so if its set to "blaster" I would do what i mentioned above and exhaust the 1st providers link until there are no more then move onto the 2nd etc. But if it was set to "roundRobin" I would use the 1st result from the 1st provider, then the 1st result from the 2nd provider etc. this is why I am using the popAllowed: false, to filter & then loop to pick without a reorder the array.

Comment: Your description is difficult to understand as far as what expected results are. You only want to return array of first instances found for a provider? And does resultant need sorting? Also no idea what `blaster` or `roundRobin` mean without some context given, or even what this `config` is used for

Comment: Sorry, I will try and explain better but will have to split across multiple comments. So the back end of the site will pass through a variable to the page which i can pick up in the JS. it will specify "blaster" or "roundRobin". Blaster meaning, use all links you have for the first provider ( ebay in the case of our accepted providers) before moving onto links from any other providers. so it would do ebayLink, ebayLink, ebayLink and when there are no more, connexityLink, connexityLink etc.

Comment: roundRobin would do this differently. It would take the first link from ebay, then then first from connexity, then the first from ECN etc so it would be like ebayLink, connexityLink, ECNLink, then it would go again with their next links ebaySecondLink, connexitySecondLink, ECNsecondLink

Comment: For this reason, I am attempting not change the order of the array, but simply filter out by adding on the popAllowed: false. The I would like to loop over the objects left, looking for the correct provider each time. Hopefully that explains more clearly? Sorry about confusing description!

Comment: In terms of expected result, I just want it to return the 1 object each time, then the next time the button is clicked, then function runs again. This time it will grab the next result, as the last one would have been filtered out using its "popAllowed":false attribute.

Comment: You need to provide all the proper details in the question. There is no button mentioned.. or what that button should specifically do etc